# auto build when code (.cs) is updated - visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-application-project

In VS, automatic build is performed everytime whenever there is change in .aspx file. It will not build solution when only code file(s) is/are updated. In my case, it is a web application project in c# (VS12).

I update code frequently and press <kbd>F5</kbd> in my browser and forget to build. Is there a way that visual studio will start performing automatic build  even if only cs file(s) is/are changed..?

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio out of the box does not have this kind of support.

You can achieve this with an extension like [.NET Demon](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-demon/).

Comment: Isn't there any free tool available for the same thing..?